# Excel OnChange event

Tags: excel

I want to update a cell with the date-time when a value is entered to another one so,

How can i change the value of the B column to the date-time when a value is entered to A?

Is there something like, if-then-else?

I tried conditional formatting but with no success.

Could someone please post a working example?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
=IF(A3<>"",IF(B3="",NOW(),B3),"")
```

The values will be in column A and the time-stamp in column B. Also, you'll have to enable iterative calculations in the options.

Note that this will generate a time-stamp only when a value is first entered in Column A. To use this, the way you want, instead of normally editing a cell's value, you'll have to delete it and re-enter a new value.

I fear this is just a work-around and not a complete solution. I'll update this in case I find something more convenient.

Comment: Thank you ronin, i will definitely try this :)

Comment: This will work but may be recalculated each time every formula is recalculated (on opening for instance...) - I have to check this though

Comment: Since you seem to be interested in the edit history, try [this one](http://www.tlookup.com/) out

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative event procedure that handles the case where the user updates more than one cell at a time (i.e. pastes a block of cells).

When working with the `Worksheet_Change` event procedure it is imperative to turn off event handling at the beginning and to make sure it always gets turned back on at the end.

Note that I intentionally left out the formatting of the time stamp as previous examples stripped off the date. If the column is not already formatted and you need to format it, I suggest you add a line of code to set the `.NumberFormat` property.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Target.Resize(ColumnSize:=1).Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = Now
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The case of tracking changes in Column A is easy; other columns can be a bit trickier when users paste blocks of cells. For example, if you want to capture changes to Column D, the code needs to handle the case when cells C2:D2 are pasted in which case `Target.Column` = 3. (Use the `Intersect` method or also look at the `Target.Columns.Count` property.

Comment: +1 good point on the multi-cell update, too often overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

You could have tried this by yourself, couldn't you?
In my opinion, the hardest part was to think about the `Change` event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False

ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = Format(Now, "h:mm")
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You can change the `Format` content to whatever you need.

Comment: Hello, yes i definitely could, i'm a programmer for 10 years but really don't know to use excel, nor am i the greatest with math actually :) I don't even know where i am going to add this code to but i will try it. Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood your title... What I've shown is an [Event Procedure](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx), you need to add this code to the worksheet: right-click on the tab and click on `Edit code` and copy-paste the code from my answer (have a look to the link above in my comment too)

Comment: +1 - but suggest you move your EnableEvents = False to line 3 after your Intersect test :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'when entering data in a cell in Col A
On Error GoTo enditall
    Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Cells.Column = 1 Then
        n = Target.Row
        If Me.Range("A" & n).Value <> "" Then
            Me.Range("B" & n).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
        End If
    End If
enditall:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

How to use?

1. Right-click on the sheet tab and "View Code".
2. Paste the code into that sheet module.
3. Alt + q to return to the Excel window.

[Click here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3mN8H2AV4UCM2EwYzAwNzQtZjhhMS00OGJkLTllZjktMmVlN2E1MWVlYWRk) for a sample file...

Answer (score 0):

The formula =NOW() is volitile, meaning it will recalculate whenever anything in the workbook is changed so if you use that, you should have no problem.

On a seperate note, you can create UDFs that are volitile as well by simply adding `Application.Volitile` inside the code.