# Reference Cell to the left of last used cell of another column

Tags: if-statement, reference

I am trying to get an excel forumal that will populate that Cell's text referenceing the last used cell in another column.

For example I want the output to be the date of the last used cell in column "B" of ($60.00) to populate the `"1/18/13"` in a sepereate cell. Does anyone know a formula that will give me the 1/18/13

```
row#    A         B         C
 10   1/12/13   $51.00
 11   1/15/13   $15.00
 12   1/18/13   $60.00
 13   1/31/13             $89.00
 14   2/15/13             $43.00
 15   2/18/13             $33.00 
 16   3/15/13             $100.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onChange event in a macro, or the `NOW()` function as described in [Excel OnChange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494658)

Comment: My posting didn't quite format like I thought it would. I am trying to reference the last cell with text in column B which is a dollar figure and get the corresponding date of that transaction in column A. However Column A is not a datestamp it is a date entered manually as the timestamp would not be accurate.

Comment: @JoshuaMyers I would look at a macro, hooking into the onChange event.  Unless your heart is set on using only in-built functions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to write the macro or reading the coding to understand if there is a macro that would fit what I'm looking to do.

Comment: @JoshuaMyers Unfortunately, I don't have Excel any more (we all went open source).  If I can get on a machine which has one I'll write one for you, it'd be very simple.  Did you look at the question I suggested?  It looks like there may be a non-macro solution.

Comment: @JoshuaMyers [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8495620/442351) suggests `=IF(A3<>"",IF(B3="",NOW(),B3),"")`

Comment: =LOOKUP(2,1/(C10:C65000<>""),$A$10:A$55000)

This is the formula for doing a reference to another adjacent column based on the last cell with data in another column.