# sum up hours at specific row in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to find a formula to sum up some specific working hours.
[image]
[image]

From the first two sheets people can track when they work on a specific ID(Project) So you see that Lukas worked on ID 2 and Chinaedu on ID 5 on two different days.

[image]

In this sheet the working time on an ID should be calculated automatically just by putting the ID in the first column. That means that when you put an ID into the cell on the sheet UserStories, Excel should look for exactly this ID in column P of the other sheets and return the estimated time in sum and the date. Has anybody an idea which could help me along? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What should happen if the ID belongs to a user story on which more than 1 person has worked? One row with total time without the person who did the work? Or row added for each additiontal person?

Comment: I would say: Write a vba sub which adds the row(s) to the UserStories sheet (preferably in a module you add to the workbook). And add an onChange-event on the UserStories sheet which calls that sub.

Comment: @PeterPesch a row should be added for each additional person

Comment: An example for the onChange event can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494658/excel-onchange-event - In your case, you'll have to check whether the change took place in the first column.